# Can't parse names and phones out of different containers from a webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get name and phone from each container from a webpage's landing page using requests. My current attempt can fetch me only the names. `I don't find any idea to rectify the existing loop so that it can include the phones together with names`.

[website address](https://sdcds.org/dental-directory/)

How can I scrape the names along with phones from there?

I've tried with:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://sdcds.org/dental-directory/'

r = requests.get(link,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html.parser")
for item in soup.select("h3 > a"):
    print(item.text)
```

This is the relevant html for one such container:

```
<h3 class="dentist-h3"><a style="text-decoration: underline; color: #5e76a2;" href="/dental-directory/view-dentist/?ID=16835">Matthew  Osmak , DDS</a></h3>
General Practice<br>
Pomerado Dental<br>
15835 Pomerado Rd Ste 301<br>

Poway, CA 92064<br>
Tel: <a href="tel:+1(858) 487-4888">(858) 487-4888</a><br>

<a href="mailto:jarvek7@yahoo.com">jarvek7@yahoo.com</a><br>

<br>
<hr>
<br>&nbsp;<h3 class="dentist-h3"><a style="text-decoration: underline; color: #5e76a2;" href="/dental-directory/view-dentist/?ID=16232">Robert Ian Goldenberg , DDS</a></h3>
General Practice<br>

2602 Washington St<br>

Julian, CA 92036<br>
Tel: <a href="tel:+1(760) 765-1675">(760) 765-1675</a><br>

<a href="mailto:robertgoldenbergdds@gmail.com">robertgoldenbergdds@gmail.com</a><br>

<br>
<hr>
<br>&nbsp;
```

Comment: you can just parser the html tag or you can use webdriver

Comment: Why would anybody go for selenium when the content are available in page source @ Zhubei-Federer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some dentists that doesn't have phone. This script will get all the names found on page + their phones (or empty string if they don't have one):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://sdcds.org/dental-directory/'

r = requests.get(link,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html.parser")

out, name, tel = [], '', ''
for tag in soup.select('h3.dentist-h3, a[href^="tel"]'):
    if tag.name == 'h3':
        if name:
            out.append((name, tel))
        name, tel = tag.get_text(strip=True), ''
    elif tag.name == 'a' and 'Tel:' in tag.find_previous(text=True):
        tel = tag.get_text(strip=True)

out.append((name, tel)) # append last one

for name, tel in out:
    print('{:<50} {}'.format(name, tel))
```

Prints:

```
Mina  Raffo , DDS                                  (619) 456-8973
Arthur David Santos , DDS                          (619) 334-8743
Nicholas  Dovey , DMD                              (619) 232-3774
Frederick U Soldau , DDS                           (858) 454-6124
John E Duling , DDS                                (760) 728-9558
Jimmy Igen Wang , DDS                              (858) 487-6428
,                                                  
Alexis Laine Louie , DMD                           (619) 276-0963
Karina  Scalercio , DDS                            
S. Roya  Sadrian , DDS                             (858) 780-9794
```